# Typescript: Yarn Workspaces IDE Support (IntelliJ, VSCode ...)

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, monorepo

Working on a larger typescript project we decided to move the code to a monorepo with **yarn workspaces**.

We use **webpack** to build and bundle and everything works well (especially the linking between local modules/packages).

Since yarn workspaces will store most of the node_modules in the mono repo's root folder, the IDE (IntelliJ as well as VSCode) have problems resolving the imports to any node_modules when coding inside a "inner" project (so called "package" of a monorepo).

The strange thing is that imports are not known but on the other hand most of the time you can navigate to the correct source / definition within the IDEs for the same import if you write it down manually.

We have tried to tell IntelliJ to look into another folder for node_modules, but still not satisfying.

Please **share your experience with yarn workspaces / monorepo** (e.g. lerna) and how you develop the code living in these monorepos.

Which IDE do you use?

Did you add any special configurations to the IDE and/or package.json, tsconfig.json?

Comment: Related: WebStorm now supports Monorepos: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/04/webstorm-2018-1-1/

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Izhaki/mono.ts

It uses yarn workspaces and marry well with VSCode. I hope the README is clear enough.

Basically, use two (parallel) typescript configuration trees:

- **Pre-build** - uses aliases (for VSCode, tests, webpack, etc).
- **Build** - uses typescript 3 project references for publishing essentially.

Answer (score 3):

IDEA doesn't provide any support for Yarn workspaces; if you miss it, please follow [WEB-29250](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29250) and linked tickets for updates.
You can try adding path mappings to your `tsconfig.json` - see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207656825/comments/115000529564

Answer (score 3):

Upodate as of 2018.1.1 IntelliJ now supports yarn workspaces so if you use this there should not be a problem.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/04/webstorm-2018-1-1/

Answer (score 1):

> Please share your experience with yarn workspaces / monorepo (e.g. lerna) and how you develop the code living in these monorepos.
>
> Which IDE do you use?

Since you are asking. I basically ran into the same issues as you did. One solution I was looking into was [disable hoisting node modules as described here](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/). Unfortunately it seems it is not yet in the stable release.

What I ended up was ditiching workspaces *for now* until they fix either the IDE or release the nohoist option. Instead I am using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for now. It is less convenient but it does not hoist so that both the build tools and the IDE are satisfied.

Oh, I am also using IntelliJ (ultimate)